# Is there any way to require methods and members to be explicitly annotated as "public" in scala?

Tags: scala

After developing in scala for a while, I've noticed that a lot of people tend to use default visibility for methods and class members when they should really be private. I think this is usually done out of convenience and laziness and it's hard to enforce discipline to explicitly type `private` in all such cases.

Therefore, I'm interested in seeing if there's a way to require the use of an annotation, (for example, methods could be tagged as `Public` using `scala.tools.nsc.doc.model.Public`). Is there an easy way to require that all default visibility methods/members are tagged with such an annotation (possibly using maven or scalastyle)?

Comment: No please, let's not go back to java land ;) :P

Comment: You could make a macro for this

Comment: https://github.com/puffnfresh/wartremover

Comment: @BenReich I don't see any way to do it with a macro, at least without requiring an annotation on every top-level class/object/trait.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I meant with the annotation!  I also don't see a way to do this without the annotation.  I don't like this idea, but it would require the writer to use `@Public` on every public method.  He or she could in fact only use `@Public` and eschew the default `public` modifier.

Comment: @BenReich The problem is that this just replaces the "problem" of developers not remembering to use `@Public` when they add a new public member with the problem of not remembering to use the `@RequirePublic` macro annotation when they add a new top-level type. WartRemover is different in this sense; once you write the check and add it into the build, there's nothing to forget.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Makes sense to me!  I'll have to check it out.